# Java Is "cursor move" to next line counts as a new line? 'System.out.println'

Tags: java, stdout

My friend asked me a question that I wasn't sure if I gave him the right answer.

Given that code:

```
System.out.print("Hello");
System.out.println(" There");
System.out.println("How are you?");
```

**Question:** How many lines are in the output?

So, the text is  actually two lines, but by definition

> The println() method is similar to print() method except that it moves the cursor to the next line after printing the result. It is used when you want the result in two separate lines. It is called with "out" object.

After reading this I was wondering if courser move to new line counts as a line, so there are 3 lines in the output and not 2 as visible.

I ran a simple test outputinge a string with two "\n" characters (two println statements) to a file and then counting the number of lines, got the result of 2.

When i wrote the test code I've noticed that VS code, when pressing "Enter" for new line counts the cursor move as new line.

I'll be gald to hear your answers!
Thanks!

Comment: Two lines. The first print starts the first line. The println starts a second line. The final statement continues on the second line. It doesn't end with a newline, so that's it. Two lines.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited, the third line in the code is println, not print.

Comment: Then it might technically be three lines, but given that the final newline is on the end of the second line, some people would say two lines.

Answer (score 0):

After running a simple code:

```
// PrintTest.java
public class PrintTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

When I run it from windows Powershell, CMD and Linux terminal I get consistent output:

```
Username@env> java PrintTest
Test
Username@env>
```

The output is only 1 line and then the program terminates.

For

```
System.out.print("Hello");
System.out.println(" There");
System.out.println("How are you?");
```

2 lines and then terminates.